# How to check if user is logged from the middleware in Nuxt3 Auth0

Tags: middleware, auth0, nuxtjs3

I built a simple login page in Nuxt3 using Auth0 and it works. Now I am trying to build a middleware which will redirect users who are not authenticated to the login page. I am able to use this.$auth0.isAuthenticated variable on the login.vue page but not in my middleware because I get error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$auth0')". How can I access isAuthenticated variable from the middleware?

this is login page: pages/login.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-if="isAuthenticated">hey {{ user }}</p>
    <p v-else>you are not authenticated</p>
    <button @click="login">Log in</button>
    <button @click="logout">logout</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      user: this.$auth0.user,
      isAuthenticated: this.$auth0.isAuthenticated
    };
  },
  methods: {
    login() {
      this.$auth0.loginWithRedirect();
    },
    logout() {
      this.$auth0.logout({ returnTo: 'http://localhost:3000' });
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

and this is middleware page (middleware/auth.global.ts)

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(() => {
  if (this.$auth0.isAuthenticated) {
    console.log('authenticated')
  }
  else {
    console.log('not authenticated')
  }
})
```

Comment: You probably need to import `auth0` in a more "Composition API" way.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the middleware approach but I've been facing the same problem.

I ended up with this in the `<script setup>` section of my layout:

```
import { authGuard } from "@auth0/auth0-vue"; 

const thisRouter = useRouter();

thisRouter.beforeEach(authGuard);
```

I feel this is not 100% correct but it seems to work.